# EM Daemon is not running

Tags: linux, oracle

I have installed Oracle Database 11gR2 on OS Oracle Linux 7.7
while i try to start server using below command its started

```
[oracle@localhost dbhome_1]$ emctl start dbconsole
Oracle Enterprise Manager 11g Database Control Release 11.2.0.1.0 
Copyright (c) 1996, 2009 Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.
http://localhost:1158/em/console/aboutApplication
Starting Oracle Enterprise Manager 11g Database Control .... started.
------------------------------------------------------------------
Logs are generated in directory /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/localhost_DB11G/sysman/log
```

But i try to display status then its display EM not running

```
[oracle@localhost dbhome_1]$ emctl status dbconsole
Oracle Enterprise Manager 11g Database Control Release 11.2.0.1.0 
Copyright (c) 1996, 2009 Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.
http://localhost:1158/em/console/aboutApplication
EM Daemon is not running.
------------------------------------------------------------------
Logs are generated in directory /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/localhost_DB11G/sysman/log
```

How to fixed it?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Comment: okay @jww Thanks

Comment: what do the logs say?